# how can list files in a specific folder in Xcode/Swift?

Tags: swift

I need to know how I can list a group of files stored in a specific project folder. I currently use this code but it only serves to list all the files contained in the app bundle. I need to only list the files contained in a specified project folder.
my code:

```
 static   func readFile(){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt")
        
        var string : String = ""
        
        do {
           string =  try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        catch{
            print("error")
        }
        
        print(string)

    }
```

Comment: What does *specified project folder* mean exactly? Basically `FileManager` is your friend.

Comment: Your app at runtime is far from the project structure. Please update your question and be more specific about what you are trying to do exactly.